# Chef LWRP calling issue

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, lwrp

I am creating LWRP for a cookbook `azuretrafficmanager`, steps are following

- Created Resource: `traffic_manager.rb`

  ```
  actions :create   
  default_action :create    

  attribute :resource_group_name
  attribute :profile_name
  attribute :subscription
  attribute :traffic_manager
  attribute :azure_token
  ```
- Created Provider: `traffic_manager.rb`

  ```
  def whyrun_supported?
     true
  end

  action :create do
    converge_by("Creating.") do
      traffic_manager_processor = TrafficManagers.new(@new_resource.resource_group_name,
                                                 @new_resource.profile_name,
                                                 @new_resource.subscription,
                                                 @new_resource.traffic_manager,
                                                 @new_resource.azure_token)
      traffic_manager_processor.create_update_profile
    end # Move on next line, copy/paste error or root cause ?

    @new_resource.updated_by_last_action(true) 
  end
  ```
- And then I am calling this in my recipe

  ```
  azuretrafficmanager_traffic_manager 'createtrafficmanager' do
    resource_group_name resource_group_name
    profile_name profile_name
    subscription subscription
    traffic_manager traffic_manager
    azure_token azure_token
    action :create
  end
  ```
- The above method of calling lwrp isn't working, but when i try the second method which is:

  ```
  azuretrafficmanager_traffic_manager 'createtrafficmanager' do
    resource_group_name resource_group_name
    profile_name profile_name
    subscription subscription
    traffic_manager traffic_manager
    azure_token azure_token
    action :nothing
  end.run_action(:create)
  ```
- By following this method(run_action) of calling lwrp, it is working perfectly.

The problem is, why the first syntax of calling lwrps isn't working?

Comment: I edited your question to be able to read it. There was some syntax error, is it your root cause or is the actual question really reflecting your real code ?

Comment: And what is your version of chef ?

Comment: Is your resource `traffic_manager.rb` file in the appropriate directory? In [Chef's documentation](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html) you can see it must be placed inside `resources/` directory.

Comment: @Tensibai Thank You for editing it. The question reflecting my real code, and there is another problem came up, for which i am editing my question.

Comment: @Tensibai Chef version is 11.18.12

Comment: @Navarro I am following the same directory structure for lwrps.
`resources/traffic_manager.rb`
`providers/traffic_manager.rb`

Comment: I can see only one reason it works at compile time and not at converge time, are you require the gem for `TrafficManagers` class in your recipe ? IIRC the default for LWRP to use inline_resources has been defaulted to true in 11.16 or 11.18, So maybe at converge time it can't find the Class, but that should raise an exception... Can you run with `-l debug ` to get a better idea of what's going wrong ?

Comment: @Navarro The documentation you're pointing to is the custom_resource syntax, available since v 12.5. The LWRP syntax use separated resource and providers files and was the only syntax available before 12.5.